# Is there a way to stop "hack-local-variables" from prompting for confirmation?

Tags: file-local-variables

After creating a document programmatically I need to enable the local variables in the file and with `hack-local-variables` I always get prompted to confirm.

It is annoying and interferes with the concept of creating stuff programmatically.

Is there a way around it?

Isn't that what `safe-local-variable-values` is supposed to protect from, or does that apply only to buffer-local or file-local level?

Comment: What is the value of `enable-local-variables`?

Comment: `enable-local-variables` is `t`

Comment: IIUC, you have variables already added to `safe-local-variable-values` and then you call `hack-local-variables` in your code on a file that includes those variables in its file-local variable section and you get a prompt? Just trying to understand so I can try to reproduce.

Comment: I think the `safe-local-variable-values` applies to the specific buffer and I need something that applies to all buffers. I am using the same code in different buffers but I expect the variables to be applied automatically in each one.

Comment: I don't think that's true: `safe-local-variable-values` is a cumulative list. Are you sure you are formatting it correctly?

Comment: If you are willing to live dangerously, you might want to set `enable-local-variables` to `:all` and avoid the queries.

Comment: After checking the docs on `safe-local-variable-values` I realize that the setting applies to the `variable\value` combination which is why it doesn't work. I probably have to set `enable-local-variables all` temporarily and make sure to restore its former value when there is an exception.